# NSMutable array search duplicate

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have an array with NSDictionary - 3 key 3 values, and I need to search for duplicate objects and count them

- first key - check (1 / 0)
- second key - weight ( 0 - 200)
- and third key - approach (1 - 6)
- ignored - key check

Code:

```
NSMutableString *newtext = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *original = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[_myExercise objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"myApproach"]];
NSMutableArray *myArr = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[_myExercise objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"myApproach"]];

for (int i = 0; i < [original count]; i ++) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < [myArr count]; j ++) {
        if ([original containsObject:[myArr objectAtIndex:i]]) {
            count ++;
            NSLog(@"нашед %d", count);
            [original removeObjectAtIndex:0];
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"%@", original);

    NSString *myStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d Х %@ Х %@", count, [[myArr objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"repeat"], [[myArr objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"weight"] ];
    [newtext appendString:myStr];
}
```

Comment: It isn't clear what you are trying to do. Or what the code is trying to do. What is the 'j' index for? Why do you always "[original removeObjectAtIndex:0];" if the original array containsObject:myArr objectAtIndex:i] (which will always be true since myArr should have the same contents as original). This code will basically just remove everything from original.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you can do, create a new dictionary that will have in key the object that is duplicated, and in value the number of duplications :

```
NSMutableDictionary * newDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:[originalDict count]];
for(id item in [originalDict allValues]){
    NSArray * keys = [originalDict allKeysForObject:item];
    if([keys count] > 1) {
      [newDict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:[keys count]] forKey:item];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I assume that what you want is myArr to contain the original array without duplicates:

```
NSMutableString *newtext = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
NSArray *original = _myExercise[indexPath.row][@"myApproach"];
NSMutableArray *myArr = [NSMutableArray array];

// iterate over the original
for (int i = 0; i < [original count]; i++) {
    int count = 0;
    // iterate over the rest of the original
    for (int j = i + 1; j < [original count]; j++) {
        // if these items are equal…
        if ([original[i] isEqualTo:original[j]]) {
            count++;    // bump the count
            NSLog(@"нашед %d", count);
        }
    }
    if (!count) {   // if there were no dups…
        [myArr addObject:original[i]];  // add the original item to myArr
    }
    NSLog(@"%@", original);
    NSString *myStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d Х %@ Х %@", count, myArr[i][@"repeat"], myArr[i][@"weight"]];
    [newtext appendString:myStr];
}
```

Comment: why do not put it into set and then back to array?

Comment: JulianK: I was trying to minimize modifying the code he posted. You should write that up and post it as an answer… I'd vote it up. ;-)

Comment: ..I sooooo wish something like LINQ would be coming to Objective-C anytime soon...